# Running both internet- and TV-signals on coaxial?

Tags: internet, home-networking, ethernet, tv, coaxial

I have a 1) Zyxel P-2812HNU-Fx for a) home network+internet and b) landline and a 2) satellite/FTA reciever for TV.

There's already a decent coaxial network going from the utility room and to all rooms in the house.
There are also two seperate ethernet wires (we'll call them ethernet A and ethernet B) going from the utility room to the living room.
So that's a total of three networks, where the coaxial is the only one going to all rooms.

Now, we only have one TV and one phone (placed in the living room), but we have several computers placed everywhere.

I'm thinking about setting it up like this:

Landline:
Copperwire from street --> Zyxel P-2812HNU-Fx --> Landline by ethernet A --> Phone

Internet:
Copperwire from street --> Zyxel P-2812HNU-Fx --> Some RJ45 to coaxial adapter --> Coaxial network --> Several computers

TV:
Satellite reciever --> Coaxial network --> TV

For this, I will be needing a 1) RJ45 to coaxial adapter and 2) something to input two coaxial wires and output one (a coaxial splitter?).

And now for the questions:

1) Is this possible (running ethernet and TV on same coaxial)?
2) What hardware do I need for this project?

Comment: I would recommend those powerline network adapters instead.

Comment: Found a related question: http://superuser.com/a/17802/165442

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it *is* possible to set up a local network using coaxial cables - [10BASE2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/10BASE2) is the most popular example - is is very far from common. It was predominant in the late 80's, but has been since then deprecated in favor of 10BASE-T, 100BASE-TX and 1000BASE-T (Ethernet, Fast Ethernet and Gigabit Ethernet, respectively). These are the common network connectors you find on pretty much every computer, laptop, modem, router and network device on the market.

Apart from not being used anymore (and therefore being really hard to even find hardware available to buy), coaxial networking, specifically 10BASE2, is much slower (maximum speed of 10 mbps), have a limit of 30 computers on a same network segment, and are connected to each other using a long, unique network cable in a way called "bus topology". If a single point of failure appears, the entire network goes down.

[image]

(Image taken from [The Network Encyclopedia](http://www.thenetworkencyclopedia.com/d2.asp?ref=2168))

As for having cable TV and PC networking on the same cable, that's impractical because the endpoints on both TV and PCs would expect the signal to follow specific protocols and to be "pure", otherwise they would interfere and scramble the communications. Because coaxial cabling for networks isn't a practical standard, I'd doubt there are relativaly modern devices designed for splitting/unsplitting the signals.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. I guess I'm just going to be using a wifi repeater then and let the big coaxial network remain only used for a single connection for TV then.

Comment: @Ali after writing this answer I did found this on amazon, but it is not cheap and I think you need one device per coax outlet: http://www.amazon.com/Actiontec-Ethernet-Adapter-Service-ECB2500CK01/dp/B008EQ4BQG/ref=pd_cp_e_0